# how to prevent nested tables in jquery tablesort from being alternating colors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have a table that I created and I am using jquery tablesorter. It sorts perfectly on the parent tables but when I add in code to collapse the children tables the alternating row colors on the parent tables gets messed up and the children tables get alternating colors. How can I prevent the children tables from getting alternating row colors and have only the parent table be alternating?

Comment: How are you "collapsing" your table rows?  Example code?

Comment: Also, what plugin are you using.  Details help on Stack Overflow =)

Comment: I am using jquery.tablesorter.js from here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ and I added in class="expand-child" to all of my children tr's that i wanted to collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the update command in the jQuery Tablesorter (if you're in fact using [**this**](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin).

```
//this refreshes the plugin 
// and is useful for dynamic tables
$("table").trigger('update');
```

Comment: I have seen in other post that there is a way to be more specific about which tr to have alternated. How could I do that?